# Unable to GetMethod() on inherited method

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a base class that has a method named "GetAllKeys" which I'm attempting to invoke via reflection.  The issue is that when I use `GetMethod()` the result is null.

```
var method = classType.GetMethod("GetAllKeys", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static );
```

This is the signature of the method from the class.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllKeys()
```

Via the debugger I can see the method exists and has the following properties.

```
InvocationFlags = INVOCATION_FLAGS_INITIALIZED | INVOCATION_FLAGS_NEED_SECURITY
BindingFlags    Static | Public 
IsDynamicallyInvokable  true    
System.Runtime.InteropServices._MethodBase.IsHideBySig  true    
System.Runtime.InteropServices._MethodBase.IsPublic true    
System.Runtime.InteropServices._MethodBase.IsStatic true
```

It looks like the `HideBySig` is a method attribute, so I can't use that in the `GetMethod()`, and I haven't had to do so in the past with other methods in the same inherited class.

What must I do to successfully retrieve this method for invocation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned this is the in the base class.  To get the method defined in the base class, you must modify your binding flags to include that:

```
var method = classType.GetMethod("GetAllKeys", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static  | FlattenHierarchy);
```

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.8), `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` does this:

> Specifies that public and protected static members up the hierarchy
>   should be returned. Private static members in inherited classes are
>   not returned. Static members include fields, methods, events, and
>   properties. Nested types are not returned.

Comment: I had never seen this before and wouldn't have thought to try `FlattenHierarchy`.  Thanks so much!